# Simple practical example to see faster async functions and promises from node 10 to node 12, and up

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, promise, async-await

Before I ask my question I want to make this clearly, I know benchmarks never tell the whole story. But my goal here is relatively simple, I want to see the performance improvement from node 10 to node 12 (and up) regarding to **async functions and promises**. I just need a rough idea to see how much improvement I can get, after all that is what here said https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async

So I try hard to find a *simple* code to do the test, then I find this from https://fibjs.org/en/docs/guide/about.md.html, which is far more easier than other test codes I can come up with.

```
var count = 1000;

async function test_async(n) {
    if (n == count)
        return;
    await test_async(n + 1);
}

function test_callback(n, cb) {
    if (n == count)
        return cb();

    test_callback(n + 1, cb);
}

function test_sync(n) {
    if (n == count)
        return;
    test_sync(n + 1);
}

async function test() {
    console.time("async");
    await test_async(0);
    console.timeEnd("async");

    console.time("callback");
    test_callback(0, () => {
        console.timeEnd("callback");
    });

    console.time("sync");
    test_sync(0);
    console.timeEnd("sync");
}

test(); //actually I also add a python timeit like code to repeat the test()
```

Running this code many times I do find node 12 shows many improvements compared to node 10. Unfortunately  I don't see many improvement from node 12 to node 14.

My question is is this test code effective in verifying the improvement of async function ?

---- update for node 16 ----

nodejs.16 was released in 2021.4.21 but to my surprise when I run using my script with node 16 its performance was even worse than nodejs 12!

As node16 V8 upgraded to V8 9.0 I had thought I should get some performance improvement. Not sure why

---- update again ----

If I just run my test once, node 16 indeed performs best. But if I run the test more than once, say 10 or 15 time, node 16 becomes worst.

I initially use some home-made `timeit` library to run the test, to reduce any unexpected factor, now I just run test like following.

```
async function test() {
    //async
    console.time('async')
    for (let index = 0; index < 15; index++) {
        await test_async(0)
    }
    console.timeEnd('async')
    //sync
    console.time('sync')
    for (let index = 0; index < 15; index++) {
        test_sync(0)
    }
    console.timeEnd('sync')
}
```

Node 16 always performed worst.

Comment: "*I had thought I should get some performance improvement*" - not sure why you had expected those, was there anything in the release notes about improvements that would affect your script?

Comment: "*When I run using my script with node 16 its performance was even worse than nodejs 12!*" - I would suggest filing an issue about this performance regression. Maybe it's expected due to shifted optimisation tradeoffs (and different code actually got an improvement), or you might have discovered a problem.

Comment: @Bergi because V8 upgraded to V8 9.0 and here https://v8.dev/blog/v8-release-89   it said "Faster calls with arguments size mismatch"

Comment: @Bergi I know that release note did n't say specifically about performance improvement about async/await. I just assume it can improvement.

Comment: It seems that optimisation is *only* improving calls with arguments size mismatch, but your benchmark code has all calls with matching size.

Comment: Yes I know, so I said "I just assume it can improvement." But the problem is I see the result is even worse, that surprised me.

Comment: @Bergi I filed an issue https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/38339 per your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @Bergi Please check my update. I found if I just run test once, node 16 indeed performs best. The reply in my issue seems to confirm that.

Comment: It's a common myth that performance always improves with updates. Usually, updates add features. That means unless attention was specifically paid to improving performance, performance if anything would decrease with updates, because there's more code to load, or more chance to introduce a bug during the update that reduces performance. Luckily people tend to catch the performance regressions when they happen and report them.

Comment: @MattWelke take a look at our discussion there (my filed issue) if you are interested

Comment: Nice, it looks like on GitHub people are considering it a legit performance regression. I'll be upgrading our app in production to Node.js 16 soon. Thank you for helping improve its performance. :3

Answer (score 0):

I noticed [node18 was released](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v18-release-announce/) and V8 JavaScript engine was upgraded to 10.1 so I did the test again and found node18 has significantly improved the test result, almost reducing the 50% of running time of node 14.

Actually although in my initial test node 16.0 was slower than nodejs 14.15, I found node 16.14.2 has performed better than node 14.19.0.

Then on the other hand I do feel the test used by fibjs is a good one.

--- update ---

Please check [State of Node.js Performance 2023](https://blog.rafaelgss.dev/state-of-nodejs-performance-2023) for the detailed performance comparison between 16.20.0, 18.16.0, and 20.0.0. But it lacks comparison for async functions/promise.